# How can I get my R Shiny App to upload and download multiple files to/from a local repository?

Tags: r, download, upload, shiny

In a Shiny app I want to enable users to upload files to a folder within the application folder, where any user is able to download those same files. Also, the files will be uploaded to a folder depending on a user input and so the folder might need to be created and so the app should be able to create the folder if necessary. Can anyone help me with my current code?

Here's my code to simplified example:

server:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {


 observe({

    if(!is.null(input$file_support)){
      dest = paste0("data/unit_processes/")
      ifelse(!dir.exists(file.path(dest, "")), dir.create(file.path(dest, "")), FALSE)
      files = file.rename(input$file_support$datapath, paste0(dest,input$file_support$name))
      a = proc_files()

    }
  })

      proc_files = reactive({
      proc_path =paste0("data/unit_processes/")

        files =  list.files(proc_path,full.names=TRUE) #drop_dir(path = proc_path)
        if(length(files)==0){
          select_file = list(selectInput("support_files","Choose files:",choices = "no support files",multiple = TRUE) )
          f_names ="no files"
          files = f_names
          shinyjs::disable("downloadSupportfiles")

        }else{
          f_names =sub('.*\\/', '', files) #was files$path
          select_file = list(selectInput("support_files","Choose files:",choices=f_names,multiple = TRUE) )
          files = data.frame(files, f_names = f_names)
          shinyjs::enable("downloadSupportfiles")
        }


        select_files = list()
        select_files[[1]] = select_file
        select_files[[2]] = files
        select_files
      })


      output$file_list = renderUI({
        selected_files = proc_files()
        selected_files[[1]]

      })

      output$downloadSupportfiles <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
          paste("output", "zip", sep=".")
        },

        content = function(fname){
          files = proc_files()
          files = data.frame(files[[2]],stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
          f_names = input$support_files
          n_files = length(f_names)
          if(f_names[1]=="no files"){
            shinyjs::disable("downloadSupportfiles")
          }
          paths = c()
          filesToSave = f_names
          for(i in 1:n_files){
              paths[i] = as.character(files$files[which(files$f_names %in% f_names[i])])
            }

          zip(zipfile=fname, files = paths) #filesToSave)

        },

        contentType = "application/zip"
      )

})
```

UI:

```
fluidPage(

h4("Upload supporting files:"),
fileInput("file_support", "Choose Files:",
          accept = c(
            "text/csv",
            "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
            ".csv"),multiple = TRUE),
hr(),


h4("Download supporting files:"),

uiOutput("file_list"),


downloadButton('downloadSupportfiles','Download Selected Files (as zip)')

)
```

Comment: Take a look at the [shinyFiles](https://github.com/thomasp85/shinyFiles) package. It seems all features you request are supported there.

Comment: @GregordeCillia thanks, I was not aware of that package. That could help but I find the examples too simplistic. Do you know of any examples of the functionality I'm after?